# Pug not closing title tag

Tags: pug, jade4j

I am trying to learn Pug. Right now I am trying to get a very simple tutorial template working, but Pug kind of acts like a feminist at Trump's inauguration.

I've managed to get the template working and display stuff. But as soon as I move the header part (which later renders into `<head>`) into a separate file and try to `include` it, all hell breaks loose. Particularly because of this line:

```
title Test template
```

What is wrong with it? Seemingly nothing... except Pug is not closing the `<title>` tag, so the rest of the document will be treated as a document title. If I add another line after it, then it closes the `<title>`, but not the one after it. Looks like Pug has trouble recognizing the last line and rendering it properly.

What am I doing wrong? Or is this a bug?

Comment: What does the include look like? Are you sure the line under it isn't indented?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. For some reason it only occurs if I don't use blocks. So if I start my header.pug with this:

```
block header
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
...
```

and include it like this:

```
include header
block header
```

it works. This must be a bug. So I just had to add blocks and it's all fine.